# Error about missing Begin of Document using \declaretheorem[]{}

Tags: errors, numbering, theorems

when i'm using codes like numberlike= or sibling= in \declaretheorem[]{}   appear the missing \begin{document} error and i don't understand why(i want the same numeration for theorems, definitions, propositions....). I'm using in my thesis the next code for latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mono=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black} 
\usepackage{float}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{amsthm}
\usepackage[]{mathtools}
\usepackage[]{bm}
\usepackage[]{thmtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\newcommand{\marcador}{\vrule height 10pt depth 2pt width 2pt \hskip .5em\relax}
\newcommand{\cabeceraespecial}{\color{Color}\normalfont\bfseries}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\medskipamount,
spacebelow=\medskipamount,
headfont=\cabeceraespecial\marcador,
notefont=\cabeceraespecial,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=1em,
headindent=0pt,
headpunct={.}
]{importante}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\medskipamount,
spacebelow=\medskipamount,
headfont=\normalfont\itshape\color{Color},
notefont=\normalfont,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headindent=0pt,
headpunct={.}
]{normal}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\medskipamount,
spacebelow=\medskipamount,
headfont=\normalfont\itshape\color{Color},
notefont=\normalfont,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headindent=0pt,
headpunct={.},
numbered=no,
qed=\color{Color}QED
]{demostracion}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=importante,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Remark,style=normal,numberwithin=chapter]{remark}
\declaretheorem[name=Corollary,style=normal]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposition,style=importante,numberwithin=chapter,sibling=theorem]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,style=importante,numberwithin=chapter,sibling=theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[name=Example,style=normal,numberwithin=chapter,sibling=theorem]{ej}
\declaretheorem[name=Definition,style=importante,numberwithin=chapter,sibling=theorem]{definition}
\let\proof=\undefined
\declaretheorem[name=Proof,style=demostracion]{proof}
```

Comment: the code you posted does not give the error that you ask about, it gives `Runaway argument?
{\declaretheoremstyle [ spaceabove=\medskipamount , spacebelow=\medskipamount \
ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.` due to mis-matched `{}` please edit the question so the code gives the error in the title, otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: did you intend to comment out the `}` here? `\newcommand{\cabeceraespecial}{%\color{Color}%\normalfont\bfseries}`

Comment: yes, sorry, i forget one space when i copy the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

to get a complete document

and at the start of the preamble add

```
\everypar{}
```

to kill the begin document error (useful sometimes for debugging but not a good

idea in a production document) then you get

[image]

which gives a pointer to the error.

`\newtheorem` has an optional argument to say to re-use an existing counter and a different optional argument to say to reset the counter under a parent counter however you can't use both of these. If you do the second (`[chapter]`) trailing optional argument is not picked up and is just typeset as text leading to the error shown.  The `thm-tools` keyval wrapper probably ought to complain and give a better error message if you use both `sibling` and `counterwithin`

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mono=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black} 
\usepackage{float}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{amsthm}

\usepackage[]{mathtools}
\usepackage[]{bm}
\usepackage[]{thmtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\newcommand{\marcador}{\vrule height 10pt depth 2pt width 2pt \hskip .5em\relax}
\newcommand{\cabeceraespecial}{\color{Color}\normalfont\bfseries}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\medskipamount,
spacebelow=\medskipamount,
headfont=\cabeceraespecial\marcador,
notefont=\cabeceraespecial,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=1em,
headindent=0pt,
headpunct={.}
]{importante}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\medskipamount,
spacebelow=\medskipamount,
headfont=\normalfont\itshape\color{Color},
notefont=\normalfont,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headindent=0pt,
headpunct={.}
]{normal}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\medskipamount,
spacebelow=\medskipamount,
headfont=\normalfont\itshape\color{Color},
notefont=\normalfont,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headindent=0pt,
headpunct={.},
numbered=no,
qed=\color{Color}QED
]{demostracion}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=importante,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[name=Remark,style=normal,sibling=theorem]{remark}

\declaretheorem[name=Corollary,style=normal,sibling=theorem]{corollary}


\declaretheorem[name=Proposition,style=importante,sibling=theorem]{proposition}



\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,style=importante,sibling=theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[name=Example,style=normal,sibling=theorem]{ej}
\declaretheorem[name=Definition,style=importante,sibling=theorem]{definition}
\let\proof=\undefined
\declaretheorem[name=Proof,style=demostracion]{proof}



\begin{document}

\end{document}
```